# problems with async jquery and loops

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, module

I am so confused. I am trying to append portals to a page by looping through an array and calling a method I wrote called addModule(). The method gets called the right number of times (checked via an alert statement), in the correct order, but only one or two of the portals actually populate. I have a feeling its something with the loop and async, but it's easier explained with the code:

`moduleList = [['weather','test'],['test']];`

for(i in moduleList) {
  $('#content').append('');
  for(j in moduleList[i]) {
   addModule(i,moduleList[i][j]); //column,name
  }
 }

function addModule(column,name) {
  alert('adding module ' + name);
  $.get('/modules/' + name.replace(' ','-') + '.php',function(data){
   $('#'+column).append(data);
  });
 }

for each array in the main array, I append a new column, since that's what each sub-array is - a column of portals. Then I loop through that sub array and call addModule on that column and the name of that module (which works correctly). Something buggy happens in my addModule method that it only adds the first and last modules, or sometimes a middle one, or sometimes none at all... im so confused!

Comment: Don't know if that this will help the issue, but IDs shouldn't start with a number. Only a letter.

Comment: My understanding was that you were not getting responses from some of your requests. Is the issue that you are not getting them in order?

Comment: If the issue is merely with the proper order, then I would suggest that your `addModule()` function create an enumerated `<span>` container in the proper column for each `$.get()` request it makes. Then when the response is received, append the result to the proper `span` number. I'll see if I can update my example.

Comment: Here's an example that should ensure the proper order: http://jsfiddle.net/kkxBH/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's not an issue with your PHP?

It works fine for me (using alternate http requests).

**Test it here:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkxBH/1/ **(updated)**

Of course, items appended into the same column may not get appended in the same order as they were sent. But rather in the order in which the response is received. Not necessarily the same.

**EDIT:** Updated to ensure proper order.

```
moduleList = [['weather','test'],['test'],['some','other']];

request = ['http://www.microsoft.com',
           'http://www.apple.com',
           'http://www.google.com'];


for(i in moduleList) {
    for(j in moduleList[i]) {
        addModule(i,moduleList[i][j], j); //column,name, j index
    }
}

    // Receive "j" from inner for() loop
function addModule(column,name, j) {

         // Reference the column
    var $column = $('#'+column);

         // Append a new <span> tag to the column that has
         //   the value of "j" as the class name
    $('<span/>',{ className:j }).appendTo($column);

    $.get(request[column],function() {
           // Append the result to the proper span in the proper column.
           // (Of course, you'll be appending your data returned.)
        $column.find('span.' + j).append(name);
    });
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

@patrick, thanks for the suggestion, but that does not resolve the problem. It has something to do with the async call, because if I set async to fase using the primitive $.ajax instead of $.get, I get my portals in the correct order :). But using sync is very bad and very slow, plus the modules themselves rely on async code inside...

Comment: (sorry, this was the only way to respond to your comment)

Comment: @Seth - Please use the comments functionality under your answer for dialog. Thanks. :o)

Comment: @Seth - That is because you are using a different user name. If you log in under your original account, you should at least be able to comment on your question. http://stackoverflow.com/users/365546/seth-vargo

Comment: @Patrick - "items appended into the same column may not get appended in the same order " - that is my main problem :(. I am trying to make a custom portal where users can customize the layout. If they are appended in the order the requests are received, then I have no way of actually remembering where the user wants his or her module...

Comment: @Seth - I updated my answer (and the live example) so that a numbered `<span>` tag set is created for each request. The result is then placed in the correct span in each column. The `j` variable needed to be passed in, so I modified `addModule` to accept that parameter as well.

Comment: @Seth - ...also, if my **updated** answer ends up being the correct solution for you, please remember to confirm by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thanks. :o)

Comment: it works now! but i don't have a checkmark... I posted this q before I actually made an account, so how do I get it to show up?

Comment: @Patrick - I can ask the question again and you can copy/paste your code and I'll give you credit for that one if it'll let me...

Comment: @Seth - Just log in using your previous account (see link below). You'll probably have to log out of the current account. It is better to not post the same question again. http://stackoverflow.com/users/365546/seth-vargo

Comment: Okay thanks! I had to do a thing where they reset my cookie because I only used my email address before, not openID, so I never actually made and account, but you're checked now. Thanks again!